# Very simple geo targeting for WordPress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, geolocation

I need to do some very basic geo-targeting for a WordPress site.

Something like:

```
<?php if ( visitor is from usa ): ?>
<?php get_footer('us'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php get_footer('other-countries'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Till now I used the GEO service provided by [ip-api.com](http://ip-api.com).
My code looks like this:

```
<?php $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/' . $ip));
$geo = $query['countryCode'];
if( $query['countryCode'] == 'US') : ?>
                    DO THIS
<?php else: ?>
                    DO THAT
<?php endif ?>
```

The problem is that the php unserialize is now deprecated and extremely slow. Ip-api [suggest to use JSON](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json) instead. But I am a total newbie and I don't know how to achieve the same results with JSON. Can someone please help me?

I know there are various plug-ins out there, but I think they are overkill for the very simple geo targeting I need.

PS: I just [learn](https://ahmadawais.com/best-api-geolocating-an-ip-address/) that I should use the code

```
$.getJSON( '//ip-api.com/json?callback=?', function( data ) {
console.log( JSON.stringify( data, null, 2 ) );
});
```

But still I need help to put together the final complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$ip = ( ! empty( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) ?
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';

$country_code = '';
if ( $ip ) {
    // 'fields' are comma-separated list of fields to include in the response.
    // No spaces between the fields. See http://ip-api.com/docs/api:returned_values#field_generator
    $url = 'http://ip-api.com/json/' . $ip . '?fields=countryCode,status,message';

    $res_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_safe_remote_get( $url ) );
    $geo = json_decode( $res_body );

    $country_code = isset( $geo->countryCode ) ? $geo->countryCode : '';
}

if ( 'US' === $country_code ) : ?>
    DO THE THIS
<?php else : ?>
    DO THE THAT
<?php endif; ?>
```

> PS: I just learn that I should use the code

Yes, [that](https://ahmadawais.com/best-api-geolocating-an-ip-address/)'s an example of doing it with jQuery.